# Angular 4 button disabled icon is not showing

Tags: html, angular, disabled-input

[Console image of the inspected element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCUZ0.png)

**Issue:** When my button has the disabled attribute and I hover over it the disabled icon is not showing.

Can someone please suggest how I can resolve this issue?

I've attached a code snippet below:

```
<form (ngSubmit)='onSubmit(form)' *ngIf="!submitted" #form="ngForm"> 
    <input required #password="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="stackDefaultData.password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control"> 
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: Share the code please

Comment: <form (ngSubmit)='onSubmit(form)' *ngIf="!submitted" #form="ngForm">
 <input required #password="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="stackDefaultData.password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control">
<button type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid">Submit</button>
 </form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<button  type="submit" disabled="!form.valid" 
  [ngStyle]="{'cursor': (!form.valid? 'not-allowed':'pointer')}">Submit</button>
```

Comment: style="cursor:not-allowed" always showing the disabled icon. if disabled is not true then it should not show.

Comment: I updated this to conditional - please see updated snippet

Comment: disable button working fine now, but form is not submitting.

Comment: Yah! I have tried the [disabled]="!form.valid" and it is working fine.Please update your answer. But still, I'm having the doubt, by default disable button will show the disabled icon also. any clarification much appreciated. :)

Comment: You can test that out by cutting out the ngStyle and see that the button will be disabled, but the not-allowed does not show.  Is that what you mean?  When you say 'form is not submitting what do you mean?'